# Store PHP array in C# list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm coding a prototype and I'm having trouble with a simple thing here. With my PHP script, I get values from my DB, values that i store in an array but i can't get to...pass this array into my C# app.

The thing is that I want to store what I get from my PHP script into a list.

Is there any ways to do this ?

My C# code:

```
public string pseudo;
public List<string> ListeMesCartes = new List<string>();
private void Start()
{
    pseudo = PlayerPrefs.GetString("JoueurPseudo");
    cartesJoueur();
}

public void cartesJoueur()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("Identifiant", pseudo);

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/projet_environnement/MesCartes.php", form);
    www.SendWebRequest();
    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
    else
    {
        // Read the returned value of the PHP script and add it to ListeMesCartes
    }
}
```

My PHP script:

```
$SRVusername="root";
$SRVpassword="";
$SRVadress="localhost";
$SRVdatabase="projet_environnement";

$connexion=mysqli_connect($SRVadress,$SRVusername,$SRVpassword,$SRVdatabase);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "1: Erreur de connexion";
    http_response_code(500);
    exit();
}
$Identifiant="Testeur";
$checkquery = "SELECT * FROM `joueurs_defis` WHERE `ID_JOUEUR`=(SELECT `ID_JOUEUR` FROM `joueurs` WHERE `PSEUDO`='".$Identifiant."');";
if($checkstate = mysqli_query($connexion,$checkquery))
{
    $MesCartes = [];
    while($MaCarte = mysqli_fetch_array($checkstate))
    {
        $MesCartes = $MaCarte;
    }
    var_dump($MesCartes);
} 
else 
{
    printf("4: Erreur lors de la requête %s\n", $checkquery);
    http_response_code(500);
    exit();
}
mysqli_close($connexion);
```

Comment: Gah, that php code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Why not use JSON? You could serialise the array in php and deserielise in c#.. you should also fix your sqli.

Comment: Also... C# is perfectly capable of querying MySql directly.

Comment: Why would any game maker want to make bdd requests from the game...

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn potentially not good idea in unity game

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn it's just a prototype, I don't need it to be secure but I'll edit my post

Comment: @FistiPaul There is a huge step between *secure* and purposefully introducing critical vulnerabilities and having abyssal coding standards